# How to check String value for nil before converting it to Double

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently I'm learning by Apple's Swift tutorials. There is a task where I need to attempt to convert String into a number.

> Create a variable total2 of type Double set to 0. Loop through the collection again, adding up all the integers and doubles. For each string that you come across during the loop, attempt to convert the string into a number, and add that value to the total. Ignore booleans. Print the total.

I am trying to use optional binding

```
else if let someItem = value as? String {
  if let someItemUnwrapped = someItem {
      total2 += Double(someItemUnwrapped) // TODO (NOT WORKING)
  }
}
```

to check if I can convert String into Double, but I receive this error:

> initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Here's my code:

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] = ["Apples": 5, "LightIsOn": false, "Score": 16.3, "IsBusy": true, "Book": "Hamlet"]
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print("Key: \(key); Value: \(value)")
}

var total2: Double = 0

for (key, value) in dictionary {
    if let someItem = value as? Int {
        total2 += Double(someItem)
    } else if let someItem = value as? Double {
        total += someItem
    } else if let someItem = value as? String {
        if let someItemUnwrapped = someItem {
            total2 += Double(someItemUnwrapped) // TODO (NOT WORKING)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have already unwrapped it in the `else if`. Why did you unwrap it again?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorMelashchenko in light of that, does the error message make sense to you now?

Comment: @Alexander, there is a String value in dictionary, not String?. Am I right?

Comment: I've tried using just one if let, but it didn't work either

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you both!

Comment: There is a String value in the dictionary - _if_ there is a value at all, and what someone put into the dictionary is a String. If the key isn’t there, then the result of accessing the dictionary is nil. Your first check should be as? Double otherwise score becomes 16. And as? String returns a string when successful which you can try to convert to Double using Double(someItem).

Comment: @IgorMelashchenko I'll fill in some details about the error. First some terms: 1) "conditional binding" (in this case, your `if let` statement) 2) "initializer" (in this case, the expression on the right hand side of the `if let _ =`). So what is it saying? The compiler expected that the type of the expression you're trying to conditionally bind to the variable `someItemUnwrapped` should have an optional type (which it will unwrap, conditionally), but instead it found a non-optional type, `String`.

Comment: You're program is expressing the equivalent of instruction a kid "go ahead, unwrap your present!" while they're holding lego brick in their hands. They're already unwrap, the instructions don't make sense in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
if let someItemCheck = Double(someItem) {
    total += someItemCheck
}
```

This will be like this:

1. Double(someItem) - to check if our `someItem` String value contains numbers like `"125"` or `"753"`
2. If this happens, we assign this value to let constant `someItemCheck`
3. And after that, we adding this value to `total2`

Comment: Your value is not optional thats why value as? String was not working but when you used Double(value) then it will either gives you result in Double or gives nil value thats why above if let is working.